# In IDA, how to optimize a long "if" condition to several "if" operation?

Tags: ida

for example:
from

```
if(a > 0x1000|| (b>>5)&0x10 || c)
{
  return 0;
}
return 1;
```

to

```
if(a > 0x1000)
{
  return 0;
}
if((b>>5)&0x10)
{
  return 0;
}

if(c){
  return 0;
}
return 1;
```

I saw a picture on twitter, he just set an option in IDA's configuration, but I didn't record it. And now I can't find it. Does anyone know it?

Comment: Are you asking about output of hexrays decompiled code?

Comment: @nevilad yes, fake C code.

Comment: When only one option, then he most likely added HO_FAST_STRUCTURAL flag to HEXOPTIONS. Adding HO_UNMERGE_TAILS to HEXOPTIONS and setting MAX_NCOMMAS to 1 may also affect if statements output.

Comment: @nevilad yes，MAX_NCOMMAS！Thanks a lot.  '2015/12/21 
ARM64 decompiler has arrived!
added MAX_NCOMMAS to limit the number of comma operators in expressions' . so it doesn't support x86. :(

Comment: Hexrays docs dont say this option is architecture specific (see https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/config.shtml), it should work for x86.